# How to control the data content of a file using the Linux system call read()?

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls, readfile

I have a file of integers separated by a newline character such as:

277 
123 
456 
. 
. 
.  
etc

I am able to read the file contents and store it in an array buffer using the read() Linux system call such as

```
// open the file
fileDesc = open(filename,O_RDONLY);
// read the file if it opened successfully

read(fileDesc, buffer, MAX_BUFF_SIZE)
```

I have more that goes into this but when I use printf (%c format) to view the content of my buffer it is storing the file contents as,

buffer[0] = 2 
buffer[1] = 7 
buffer[2] = 7 
buffer[3] =  
buffer[4] = 1 
buffer[5] = 2 
buffer[6] = 3 
. 
. 
etc

I really wanted the each buffer index to hold an entire value before each \n such as

buffer[0] = 277 
buffer[1] = 123 
buffer[2] = 456 
. 
. 
etc.

Is there any way I can control the way read() system call stores the file content into the buffer?  Or is there a better alternative for this task?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not that hard to parse the contents, but is is probably easier to just use stdio (fopen/ fgets / fscanf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have better success with the buffered C stdio library.  Here's the basic code you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp;
int n;


fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL) ... // error, could not open

while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &n) == 1) {
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: If the function fscan is already buffered, can I access the contents of this buffer?  I want to use the contents to perform math on them instead of just printing them out.

Comment: after the fscan(), the variable n will hold the value.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing textual data into numbers is not the purview of the OS-provided I/O routines.  They just deliver the file content as-is.

The C standard library provides some functions which can do the parsing.  For example, take a look at `strtol`.

Please note you'll have two buffers, one of type `char` or `unsigned char` which holds the raw data, and another of an appropriate numeric type that can hold the parsed values.